# SQL Replication

Tags: sql-server

I'm attempting to set up SQL Server replication for the first time for two servers on two different domains. Server A is the primary server which is running MS SQL Server 2014 whereas Server B is running MS SQL Server Express. I have two questions regarding this.

1. Is it possible to have replication between a SQL Server 2014 server and a SQL Server express server?
2. Is the data secure in transit. Does it transmit the data over HTTPS? Is there an option to set this or is this by default?

Also, the database tables I'll be replicating are identical.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replicate single table from SQL Express to SQL Enterprise 2014](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/194379/replicate-single-table-from-sql-express-to-sql-enterprise-2014). Regarding security, [check the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/security/replication-security-best-practices?view=sql-server-ver15) to see what applies to your situation (of which we know nothing at this time).

Comment: The example you posted is good but I'm going to opposite way. I'm going from SQL Server Enterprise to SQL Server Express. Is that allowed?

Comment: Yes it is good, because if you read the answers you'll find the info you want. *"SQL 2014 Express does actually support transactional replication, but only as the subscriber,"*

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to have replication between a SQL Server 2014 server and a SQL Server express server?
Yes, but SQL Express can be the subscriber only - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/getting-started/features-supported-by-the-editions-of-sql-server-2014?view=sql-server-2014

Is the data secure in transit. Does it transmit the data over HTTPS? Is there an option to set this or is this by default?
Yes, you can choose to use SSL to secure the connections for SQL 2014 replication - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/security/replication-security-best-practices?view=sql-server-2014